# Aggregating data by two variables using R and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I am using [NFL play-by-play data from the 2013 season](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xb78cdculs39rdr/HgU1Vip9dV) and I am looking to measure catch success rate by Wide Receivers. Essentially, I have four variables of interest: Targeted Receiver, Pass Distance, Target and Reception. I would like to obtain a data set broken down by Targeted Receiver and Pass Distance, with Targets and Receptions summarized (just a simple count) for each of the two Targeted Receiver and Pass Distance combinations (i.e. Receiver 1 Short, Receiver 1 Long).

Thank you for your help,

CLR

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, take the table `df` and keep only the columns that are relevant (Targeted Receiver, Pass Distance, Target, and Reception).

```
df <- select(df, `Targeted Receiver`, `Pass Distance`, `Target`, `Reception`)
```

Then, remove the rows where there is no receiver (e.g. a running play).

```
df <- df[!is.na(df$`Targeted Receiver`), ]
```

After that, use `group_by` from `dplyr` so that your data are grouped at the Target Receiver and Pass Distance level.

```
grouped <- group_by(df, `Targeted Receiver`, `Pass Distance`)
```

Finally, use the `summarise` function to create the count of Target and the sum of Reception.

```
per_rec <- summarise(grouped, Target = n(), Reception = sum(Reception))
```

The data will look like this:

```
  Targeted Receiver Pass Distance Target Reception
              (chr)         (chr)  (int)     (dbl)
1        A.J. Green          Deep     50        21
2        A.J. Green         Short    128        77
3      A.J. Jenkins          Deep      6         2
4      A.J. Jenkins         Short     11         6
5      Aaron Dobson          Deep     23         6
6      Aaron Dobson         Short     49        31
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question (this answer was in the Low Quality Posts review queue).